Why do the う column characters often change when used for verbs in a sentence?
I'm using WaniKani to learn vocab, and I noticed in the context sentences of most verbs, their last U column kana switches out for a different kana character?
For example, 考える (Kangaeru)
Some context sentences will just not use the る。

Here's a small question list:

What is this?
When does it usually happen?
How do I know what kana to change to?
Why does it exist?

I'm pretty new to JP, so I don't know much other than Rendaku, は, and の。Please explain it as best as you can for me!
ありがとう…

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_conjugation

Do we really not have a reference duplicate for this? :(

This is called 活用{かつよう}, which is akin to the English verb conjugation system. Just like how we say "I do", "you do", but "he does" and "she does" for the present tense, then for something happened in the past we say "I did" and "he did", Japanese also has these verb conjugations that change the ending of the verb based on tense(present, past or continuous), mood(active, passive, or causative), but not on person(no difference between first-person or third person) or on number(singular or plural).
Japanese verb conjugation is a broad topic, and it is difficult to cover all of it in this answer, as that would make it too long. I'll just go over  the ones shown in your screenshot:

考える: This is the dictionary-form, the most basic form, which could mean "to think"(infinitive), "(I/you/he/she...) think"(present) or "(I/you/he/she...) will think"(future)

考えさせてください: This is 考えさせて(let (me) think) + ください(please), and 考えさせて is the te-form of 考えさせる, which is necessary to connect to ください and other auxiliary verbs

考えさせる: This is the causative form of 考える, meaning "to let (someone) think." Here, it is implied to mean "let me think"

考えましょう: This is the polite-volitional form of 考える, which means "let's think." The non-polite version would be 考えよう, which still means "let's think," but not as polite.


There is still a whole lot more commonly-used conjugations, and you will learn how to do them gradually throughout your studies, just like an English learner would gradually learn "sing, sang, have sung," then "would sing, would have sung, will have been singing," etc. Eventually with prolonged exposure, these conjugations will come naturally as you go. 頑張れ！
P.S. 考える is a 一段(ichidan) verb, whose conjugation methods are different from 五段(godan) verbs. However, unlike English who has TONS of irregular verbs, for Japanese there are only two that's irregular(する and くる), and ALL the rest fits into either 一段 or 五段, so you'd only have to learn two ways of conjugating verbs.

You might find this video helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4simApUbuI

Thanks for this small explanation! I'll definitely have to look into this a little later, it seems like quite a complex topic to tackle as a beginner. But, I won't wait too long. I've been wanting to understand how verbs work for a while now. I'll check out the video soon.
